# How to create a table using two arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, cgi

Need a help to create a table using two arrays or files in perl cgi.

I need to create a table that print the list of directories from different path then put it into table say the title on column one says path1 and column 2 path2 and so on, and each column list the directory from that path with href link..here what I do have.

```
 opendir(D, "../abc/status") or die"$!"; 
 my @path1_dir = sort readdir D; closedir D;

 opendir(D, "../def/status") or die "$!"; 
 my @path2_dir = sort readdir D; closedir D; .... ...

 print "\n"; print "$path1_dir\n"; print "$path2_dir\n";

 #print list of directories to column-1 with title Path1
 foreach my $path (@path1_dir) { 
   print "\t\n"; 
   next if ($path =~ /^./); 
   next if ($path =~ /^\s*$/); 
  print "$path\n"; 
 }

 #this should go to the column two with Path2 title but it does not
 foreach my $path (@path2_dir) { 
   print "\t\n"; `enter code here`
   next if ($path =~ /^./); 
   next if ($path =~ /^\s*$/); 
   print "$path\n"; 
   }
```

Can someone help me on this if you can?

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of only the directories or also files?

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are trying to produce with the two lists. Are you trying to produce two columns of lists unrelated directory data or similar data. Will the result be text only or HTML? Please include some sample data and a quick mockup of the desired output.

Comment: just list of directories

Comment: say in directory ../test I do have 5 directories and in another directory say ../test-1 I do have 2 dir, the table should have two columns, column 1 will list all directories on ../test and column -2 list all directories on ../test-1

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this based on your description -- ie printing in two columns

```
    $dir1 = "../abc/status";
    $dir2 = "../def/status";
    opendir(D, $dir1) or die"$!";
    my @path1_dir = sort grep { !/(^\.|^\s*$)/ } readdir D; closedir D;

    opendir(D, $dir2) or die "$!"; 
    my @path2_dir = sort grep { !/(^\.|^\s*$)/ } readdir D; closedir D;

    print "$dir1\t$dir2\n";

    # figure out which one has more files
    $limit = $#path1_dir < $#path2_dir ? $#path2_dir : $#path1_dir;

    # print in 2 columns
    for ($i = 0; $i<=$limit; $i++) {
       printf "%s\t%s\n",
            ($i<=$#path1_dir ? $path1_dir[$i] : ""),
            ($i <= $#path2_dir ? $path2_dir[$i] : ""),"\n";
    }
```

Comment: what if I want to print them in cgi, ideally I want to print them on the page with a link <a href=\"$#path1_dir\" title=\"$path#path1_dir\">$#path1_dir</a>, so when user click on it it goes to the directory by clicking a link..how do I use those printf on last loop?..again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not clear what exactly you want, I'm guessing you want to have an `ls` style output (only directories) for an FTP or something. The variable naming might be ambiguous, but basically what it's doing is printing out one directory from each directory at a time.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %dirs;

my @dirs_to_look = qw(../abc ../def);
my $max_num_of_dirs;

foreach my $dir (@dirs_to_look) {
    # Directories that were found in $dir
    my @dirs_in_dir = grep { -d } glob "$dir/*";
    $max_num_of_dirs = scalar @dirs_in_dir
        if not defined $max_num_of_dirs or $max_num_of_dirs < scalar @dirs_in_dir;
    $dirs{$dir} = \@dirs_in_dir;
}

my @keys = sort {$a cmp $b} keys %dirs;
# Print the column titles
foreach my $key (@keys) {
    printf "%15s", $key;
}
print "\n";

for (my $i = 0; $i < $max_num_of_dirs; $i++) {
    foreach my $key (@keys) {
        my $dir = shift @{ $dirs{$key} };
        printf "%15s", $dir // "";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks but I ran to the error on this ..Type of arg 1 to shift must be array (not hash element) at ./help_on_dir_2.pl line 28, near "};"

Comment: That's weird. Could you tell me more about the directory structure when you ran it?

Comment: The `shift $arrayref` syntax is only available with newer perls (5.14 and newer?). Try `shift @{ $dirs{$key} }` instead.

Comment: Thank you @slaven, that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: before I rest my case how about if I want to print them using cgi , ideally I want to print them on the page with a link that goes to the directory by clicking something like this:print "<TR>\n"
     print "<TD><a href=\"$path1\" title=\"$path1\">$path1</a>\n";                                                                                                                           .    print "<TD><a href=\"$path2\" title=\"$path2\">$path2</a>\n";